# iPhone overflow-scrolling with fixed nav and 100% height header

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a tricky problem:
Just on a iPhone my wordpress Website does not scroll smooth. 
I have a fixed navigation and a header-image with 100% height. By now either I found a solution for the scrolling and the fixed navigation or for the 100% height of the images.

Here is the side: http://web02980.p4.imv.de/

Here is the code (just a hard abstract):

```
HTML:

<html>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <!-- some divs, just use bootstrap -->
   </nav>
   <div class="navbar-collapse sidebar" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" >
     <!-- that's the collapsing mobile sidebar with a list of navigation-points -->
   </div>
   <div id="headerBox"> 
     <!-- with a Call-to-Action-Button --> 
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <! -- the whole content -->
   </div>
   <footer> ... </footer>
  </div> <!-- end of .container-fluid -->
 </body>
</html>

CSS:

html, .container-fluid {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   min-height: 100%;
 }

.navbar-default { 
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 998;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 70px;
 }

#headerBox {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; 
  height: 100%;  
  position: relative; /* need this because the sidebar on a mobile view push the headerBox to the right side if you click on the burger-menu-button */
  left: 0;
}
```

In this case I have my header with 100% height, but on a iPhone the navigation is not fixed. If I set the body on min-height: 100% and the .container-fluid on height:100% i have a fixed navigation but can't see the header-image.